# trying SimplePing on iPhone, but the main runloop does not handle events from SimplePing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, runloop

I need a simple pinger on the iPhone. So I try to get the [SimplePing example](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html)  running on iPhone. But when i init the pinger like in the example, the main runloop does not handle the events generated by SimplePing. Here is the initcode:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

_pinger = [SimplePing simplePingWithHostName:@"192.168.210.1"];
_pinger.delegate = self;
[_pinger start];
NSLog(@"Pinger started");
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES; }
```

If I trigger the runloop directly in this function with somthing like that:

```
do {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
} while (_pinger != nil);
```

it works. So my question is, why are the events not processed in the main run loop of `UIApplicationMain`, and what do I have to do to get this done by the main runloop?

Comment: I've run into the same problem- did you eventually find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well, do something like this:

```
-(void)stopPinging
{

 NSLog(@"STOP");

 self.pinger = nil;  // or _pinger = nil in your case so that the while loop doesn't   execute again.

 [self.pinger stop]; // this method will call the Simpleping class method stop which takes care of the rest ..


}
```